# Refactor with strategy pattern and then apply SOLID principle

Tags: solid-principles, strategy-pattern

I have a C# class like below in an app, and looking at ways to refactor it.

- The `Send` method does not exist in the class. This is the solution that I came up with.
- There will be more email types in the future.
- I don't know whether I can apply the SOLID Open/Closed principle here because adding a new emailtype require this class to be modified.
- The Consumer of this service should not be concerned about the business logic, but just to know only the new `emailType` and the `customerId`. The consumer of the `EmailService` knows only what type of email to be sent and the `customerId`.

---

```
class EmailService
{
    Send(int emailType, int customerId)
    {
        switch(emailType)
        {
            case 1: SendSignupEmail(customerId);
                break;
            case 2: SendOrderEmail(customerId);
                break;
            case 3: SendCancellationEmail(customerId);
                break;
        }
    }

    SendSignupEmail(int customerId);
    SendOrderEmail(int customerId);
    SendCancellationEmail(int customerId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the `switch` with a `Dictionary` and some configuration external to the class:

Define a new interface that represents the signature of the send methods:

```
interface ISendEmail
{
    Send(int customerId);
}
```

For each send method, create a class that represents the send method.

```
class SendSignupEmail : ISendEmail
{
    public Send(int customerId){}
}

class SendOrderEmail : ISendEmail
{
    public Send(int customerId){}
}

class SendCancellationEmail : ISendEmail
{
    public Send(int customerId){}
}
```

These are the email strategies.

Now `EmailService` can become only a means by which `emailType`s are routed to the correct implementation, and it need never change for new emailTypes (**OCP**).

```
public interface IEmailService
{
    void Send(int emailType, int customerId);
}

class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, SendEmail> senders = new Dictionary<int, SendEmail>();

    public Send(int emailType, int customerId)
    {
        SendEmail email;
        if (senders.TryGetValue(emailType, out email)) //replaces the switch
        {   //found the email type, delegate the sending to the registered instance
            email.Send(customerId);
        }
        else
        {
            //unregistered email type, this is like a default case in a switch
        }
    }

    public Register(int emailType, SendEmail sender)
    {
        senders.Add(emailType, sender);
    }
}
```

Then at one point in your system you can create this service and register the email implementations:

```
var emailService = new EmailService();
emailService.Register(1, new SendSignupEmail());
emailService.Register(2, new SendOrderEmail());
emailService.Register(3, new SendCancellationEmail());
IEmailService iEmailService = emailService;
```

You should reuse this implementation and pass the same instance to the clients (**DIP**) as an `IEmailService`. Use of the interface here is **ISP**, because they do not require (and must not use) the classes `Register` method.

So as you can see, a new email implementation will just be a new class and a new registration line, achieving **OCP**:

```
emailService.Register(4, new SendSomeNewEmail(serviceItDependsOn));
```

Notice `serviceItDependsOn`, because I am using **DIP** I can inject extra services, or maybe an email template. Lots of additional complexity required by a new email can be handled without modifying either the client or `EmailService`.

This differs from usual examples of strategy pattern because of the routing to the correct strategy, but it is still externalizing the work behind an interface and the strategy implementations are supplied to the class. I think those are the key components so I would still classify this as the strategy pattern.

Comment: @plalx we don't have enough information to determine that. I took it on good faith that the original 3 methods were significantly different, not copy and pasted with different templates. For example the order one may need to load an order while the sign up mail might generate a confirmation link.

Comment: @plalx There's no need for any duplication because of this approach. The senders are free to share other classes to do "low-level" stuff, such as database access and actual sending of email. What's more is they can have their dependencies injected. Instead of inventing problems with my approach, why don't you present your own?

Comment: The reason behind passing the ```customerId```is to retrieve the data that satisfy the particular template. Moving that logic from the ```EmailService``` and just passing the values that needed to map the attributes in the template may be better design. But still the strategy to generate the email and sending is different. So, I have to agree with @Weston.

Comment: @Weston I'm just saying that `ISendEmail` seems like a poorly named abstraction. How will you name your low-level abstractions that gets injected in your `ISendEmail` abstraction? Hopefully you will get what I mean...

Comment: @plalx Yes I guess the names could be better, because it's named as what it does rather than what it is. I will give it some thought. Be interested to see your whole suggestion though.

Answer (score 3):

Strategy pattern requires you to encapsulate BEHAVIORS in order to keep your classes atomic and designed for a single purpose.

What you should do is (I'll write it in Java, but must be very very similar in C#):

```
interface Message {
    void send(int customerId);
}

class SignupMessage implements Message {
    // here you implement send method with specifics of signup behavior
}
class OrderMessage implements Message {
    // here you implement send method with order specifics
}
class CancellationMessage implements Message {
    // here you implement send method with cancellation specifics
}

class EmailService
{
    void send(Message message, int customerId) {
        message.send(customerId);
    }
}
```

One can also argue that sending logic (connecting to POP server and sending mail) is not related to message itself. Code that remains generic should not be reimplemented, so I think this version makes a lot more sense:

```
interface Message {
    void getMessage(int customerId);
    // I've assumed only messages are different between message types
}

// other classes are the same as above (only implementing "getMessage" this time)

class EmailService {
    void send(Message message, int customerId) {
        string msg = message->getMessage(customerId);
        // what follows next is logic to send bessage
    }
}
```