# Refactor multiple variabilities with a design pattern

Tags: c#, dictionary, factory-pattern, solid-principles, strategy-pattern

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597134/refactor-with-strategy-pattern-and-then-apply-solid-principle) about an Email service, there was only one variability which was the `emailType`. Now I have one more variability which is what's being passed to the strategy. It can be `customerId`, `orderId` or `cancellationId` as shown below.

The client does not have to pass all of the parameters. Some can be `null`. As an example, though the `emailType` can be `CancellationEmail`, the `cancellationId` can be null.

```
class EmailService
{
    Send(int emailType, int? customerId, int? orderId, int? cancellationId = null)
    {
        switch(emailType)
        {
            case 1: SendSignupEmail(customerId);
                break;
            case 2: SendOrderEmail(customerId, orderId);
                break;
            case 3: SendCancellationEmail(orderId, cancellationId);
                break;
        }
    }

    SendSignupEmail(int? customerId);
    SendOrderEmail(int? customerId, int? orderId = null);
    SendCancellationEmail(int? orderId, int? cancellationId);
}
```

The solution to this problem that I see is apply the strategy pattern, but use a `dictionary`.

```
interface ISendEmail
{
    Send(dictionary allIds);
}
```

But this will force to client (the app that calling the `EmailService`) to create the `dictionary`. I can move that dictionary creation to a `Factory` method.

How this code can be refactored better by applying the **SOLID** principles?

I'm open to using a container like **Unity** to solve it to eliminate some manual object construction.

Comment: Are all the id's always passed when using the `EmailService.Send(int, int, int, int)` method?

Comment: No. I updated the original question.

Comment: your `EmailService` knows *what* it sends and *how*. I would say that it should know only *how* and take *what* and a parameter, like `Send(IEmail emailToSend)`. then your clients will pass `IEmail` instance what they want to service.

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo The dictionary that mentioned in my assumed solution can have ```emailType, customerId, orderId, cancellationId```. You are suggesting an ```IEmail``` in place of a dictionary. In addition, the refactoring all the different ```Send``` methods from the ```EmailService``` is needed.

Comment: @wonderfulworld - you got me right. Refactoring will be needed. But according to GRASP and SOLID - it will be the right choice. Your service will have only one method `Send`, but you will have a different implementations of `IEmail` for each group of required parameters. And because your clients have all of these required parameters - it's the right place to create your emails right there.

Comment: When you're refactoring to design patterns, you want to make sure you understand what category of pattern you need - structure, behavioural, creational. You need to understand what it is you're doing, and find the pattern that fits. In my eyes you're changing the behaviour but the structure is rigid - so look at Strategy Pattern and Template Method.

Comment: @CallumLinington The strategy pattern is what applied to the [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597134/refactor-with-strategy-pattern-and-then-apply-solid-principle) All the ```senders``` were refactored to a class hierarchy because ```send``` method accepted only parameter. But in this current question, they vary.

Comment: IMO it doesn't change the answer, still strategy pattern, you can just group those other params into an object

Answer (score 2):

I think you are applying SOLID wrong. You are creating an abstraction that isn't interchangeable with the same intent. If you create an `ISendMail` implementation for a signup email, you cannot take it out and replace it with an implementation that sends an order email. It takes different parameters, and, more importantly, the **functional intent is different**. Therefore it should require a different abstraction.

I would create the following abstractions:

```
public interface ISignupEmailSender { void Send (int customerId); }
public interface IOrderEmailSender { void Send (int customerId, int orderId); }
public interface ICancellationEmailSender { void Send (int orderId, int cancellationId); }
```

Add the implementations for the abstractions, and inject them whenever you need.

Now, if you want to create a proxy/service to have a place to send all emails, then create `IEmailService` abstraction, and inject the email-sender above, and add a corresponding method for each email-sender. Just like you have in your current email-sender, but without the `void Send(int, int?, int?, int?)` method you currently have.

You don't gain anything by having a single method with multiple parameters for different abstractions with different behind-the-scenes implementations. It only makes things for complex. Keep it simple.

Comment: Please consider that not all the messages sent at the same time, but based on calling the ```EmailService``` with the ```emailType```. The caller to this service can be a legacy system that can't change.

Comment: If the caller cannot change, how is it going to pass additional parameter/s even with your current updated implementation of `EmailService`? Forget patterns and all for a moment. As per your old question, you only had `customerId` then. Now you have `orderId` and `cancellationId` as well. How's legacy system going to handle pass them w/o changing it's calls? Just trying to understand more about your comment above. Else I second @Maarten's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but I think you're setting a bad design.

First of all I think it's not fair see the application of the Strategy pattern in this example: you're forgetting the main abstraction, the algorithm character (the @LucianGabrielPopescu answer in your previous request), as well as the sharing of a context by all concrete strategies.
So `EmailService` should at least provide data to the business logic of concrete strategies, the different *email types*.

The most correct answer in the line of the pattern seems that by @LucianGabrielPopescu in your previous request. But where is revealed, also, how the different strategies resolve in the delegation to a polimorphic call (`Send` method). So, beyond the parts that surely there will be not proposed, the Strategy Pattern allegedly manifests as wrong just because it **degenerates into an implementation of different strategies in chief of implementations of a polymorphic call** the `Send` method of an `EmailType` referred by `EmailService` abstractly (other missing step).

Stepping back different strategies, different behaviours, appear to refer only to the assembly of a particular type of email, which recalls me the *Builder Pattern*. It could thus result in some form of message formatting according to a more or less fixed pattern via a ***Builder Pattern***.

Further changing perspective I would start by considering the various *actions* which relate the different email types. The characterization `EmailType` (understood as some kind of interface) could indicate only a way to communicate this action, which at this point suggest an interaction via Email.

Then I would draw like this:

```
                                                        +---------------------+
+---------------+                                       |    EmailService     |
| Action        +-------------------+------------------->                     |
+---------------+                   |                   +---------------------+
| ID            |         +---------+------------+      |                     |
|               +---+     |                      |      |   Send(Message)     |
| trigger       |   |     | InteractionMessage   |      |                     |
|               |   |     |                      |      +---------------------+
| message(s)    |   |     +----------------------+
|               |   |     |  Collect(reveiverID) |
| workflow      |   |     |                      +--------------------+   (builder pattern)
|               |   |     +----------------------+                    |   +-----------------------------------------+
+---------------+   |                                                 |   |                                         |
                    |                                                 |   |      (Action)InteractionMessages        |
                    |                                                 +---+                                         |
                    |                                                 |   +-----------------------------------------+
                    |     +----------------------------------+        |    (classification of messages according to a
                    |     |                                  |        |    scheme of interaction and an assembly of
                    |     | ActionWorkflow                   +--------+    parts implemented by a concrete builder)
                    +---<>+                                  |
                          +----------------------------------+
                          |                                  |                    
                          | GetInteractionMessage(receiverID)|
                          |                                  |      
                          +----------------------------------+

              Action    InteractionMessages  ActionWorkflow                                                                     
Signup           x                 x                 x
Order            x                 x                 x
Cancellation     x                 x                 x
```

This would require 9 concrete types, according to the table in the diagram, but in the face of the abstraction of `Action`*(s)* and `Interaction`*(s)* via some type of `Communication`*(s)*

Answer (score 1):

Why are you cheating with SOLID principles anf Strategy Pattern when **your design it's obviously NO Object Oriented**?

I posted another answer, that i'd like to correct here in terms of class diagram. It's debatable design but it's OO.

[image]

in some kind of C++-like pseudo language, with no `virtual keyword` detailed, you could have:

```
Interaction Workflow::startInteraction(InteractionTypeEnum interaction_type) {
    Interaction interactionObj = InteractionTypeFactory::getInteraction(scheduledAction, interaction_type);
    interactionObj.trigger();
    return interactionObj;
}

void EmailInteraction::trigger() {
    Message messageObj = interactionMessageBuilder();
    action.trigger();
    EmailService::Send(messageObj);
}

Message Interaction::interactionMessageBuilder() {
     with(action.messages) {
     ...
     }
     return messageObj;
}
```